# IE9 iframe scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an interesting "issue" that only happens in IE9.

There are some forms on our web site that use iframes (the forms live on other sites we have no control over - and example would be Salesforce.com).

The scrolling attribute is set to "no". This shuts off the scrollbars and prevents scrolling in all browsers *except IE9*.

In IE9, the user can still scroll in the iframe by clicking and dragging or using the arrow keys when the iframe has focus.

My question is: does anyone know of a way to prevent this? I assume if I had access to the source I could create a div and set the div to be narrower than the iframe so the content wouldn't overflow, but I don't have access to the iframe source code, so that's not an option.

Any suggestions on this one? It's been driving me nuts and I'm close to saying it's not possible.

Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, I've seen this behavior in a variety of browsers.  I'm assuming that the frame is not the same size of the page contained within it?

Comment: +1, I've noticed this behavior as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting scrolling attribute of iframe to "no" will just hide the scrolls from being appearing in IE for that iframe even if they are needed.

To avoid this you must arrange the contents of iframe such that no scrolls are needed.

Comment: Much as I hate to say it, Suhas, I think you're right. The content needs to be inside a div that's smaller than the iframe it's contained in.